# How to make an GAE app downloadable from permentnent prohibited

Tags: java, google-app-engine

When managing my application in https://appengine.google.com I stupidly click on **permanently prohibit code downloads** button in the Version section. It makes the application unable to be downloaded (follow this tutorial https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp)

Can anybody tell me how to make the application downloadable again?

Comment: Well, you still have the original code, don't you?  For instance, in eclipse?

Comment: Unfortunately I have just formatted my hard disk for reinstall windows, so I think about downloading the code. But when I access the application I found out that it has been prohibited :(.

Answer (score 2):

Its **permanent**. So you **cannot** enable it again. If you could, there would be no use of it. You were warned:

> Warning: No one—including yourself—will ever be able to download the code using the appcfg download_app command.

Some *bad* options:

- Create a new application and upload your code there (if you have it). *Note: You cannot delete your application and use the same ID again*
- Write to Google and ask them to enable it again (they will probably decline)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I did it accidently, now maybe I have to write to Google. Hope they can help :(

Comment: Another huge mistake you made is not having source control or backups of your code. Doubt google can help you :(

Comment: Yes, I really didn't think about keeping that application. But one day my boss suddenly asked me to copy the source code for him ...